# where is memory gone (no, not buffers or cache)

Tags: linux, memory

can anyone tell me where the memory is gone:
(no, this time neither buffers nor cache)

```
# free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       3928200    3868560      59640          0       2888      92924
-/+ buffers/cache:    3772748     155452
Swap:      4192956     226352    3966604
```

top, sorted by memory, descending:

```
top - 13:42:06 up 1 day,  3:47,  2 users,  load average: 0.08, 0.12, 0.36
Tasks: 228 total,   1 running, 227 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu0  :  2.0%us,  4.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 90.1%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  4.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu1  :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,100.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   3928200k total,  3868020k used,    60180k free,     2896k buffers
Swap:  4192956k total,   226048k used,  3966908k free,    82068k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 3863 root      20   0  902m 199m 3296 S    7  5.2  99:08.77 ndsd
21906 root      20   0  138m 9076 2988 S    0  0.2   0:00.02 sfcbd
 2332 root      20   0  126m 4660 1332 S    0  0.1   0:17.72 mono
 4243 wwwrun    20   0  683m 4468  668 S    0  0.1   0:07.38 java
 2994 root      20   0  202m 2288 1660 S    0  0.1   6:10.02 httpstkd
 4338 root      20   0  184m 2240 1112 S    0  0.1   0:00.52 namcd
21898 root      20   0 32368 1832 1256 R    1  0.0   0:00.08 top
```

In fact, some time ago oom kicked in and crashed the system (kernel panic), and I'm afraid we're again not far from that point....

UPDATE

```
 # cat /proc/meminfo                                                     
 MemTotal:        3928200 kB                                             
 MemFree:           51336 kB                                             
 Buffers:            2964 kB                                             
 Cached:            72876 kB                                             
 SwapCached:        29128 kB                                             
 Active:           233440 kB                                             
 Inactive:          88040 kB                                             
 Active(anon):     188920 kB                                             
 Inactive(anon):    56752 kB                                             
 Active(file):      44520 kB                                             
 Inactive(file):    31288 kB                                             
 Unevictable:           0 kB                                             
 Mlocked:               0 kB                                             
 SwapTotal:       4192956 kB                                             
 SwapFree:        3966824 kB                                             
 Dirty:                32 kB                                             
 Writeback:             0 kB                                             
 AnonPages:        225112 kB                                             
 Mapped:            11356 kB                                             
 Shmem:                32 kB                                             
 Slab:            1624080 kB                                             
 SReclaimable:      13740 kB                                             
 SUnreclaim:      1610340 kB                                             
 KernelStack:        4176 kB                                             
 PageTables:        10500 kB                                             
 NFS_Unstable:          0 kB                                             
 Bounce:                0 kB                                             
 WritebackTmp:          0 kB                                             
 CommitLimit:     6157056 kB                                             
 Committed_AS:    2397684 kB                                             
 VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB                                          
 VmallocUsed:      441372 kB                                             
 VmallocChunk:   34359246755 kB                                          
 HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB                                             
 HugePages_Total:       0                                                
 HugePages_Free:        0                                                
 HugePages_Rsvd:        0                                                
 HugePages_Surp:        0                                                
 Hugepagesize:       2048 kB                                             
 DirectMap4k:       10240 kB                                             
 DirectMap2M:     4184064 kB
```

slabtop

```
 Active / Total Objects (% used)    : 9041019 / 9207548 (98.2%)          
 Active / Total Slabs (% used)      : 401132 / 401156 (100.0%)           
 Active / Total Caches (% used)     : 91 / 159 (57.2%)                   
 Active / Total Size (% used)       : 1491537.88K / 1519791.56K (98.1%)  
 Minimum / Average / Maximum Object : 0.02K / 0.17K / 4096.00K           

  OBJS ACTIVE  USE OBJ SIZE  SLABS OBJ/SLAB CACHE SIZE NAME              
4240470 4240319  99%    0.12K 141349       30    565396K pid             
2245140 2219675  98%    0.25K 149676       15    598704K size-256        
2238090 2210087  98%    0.12K  74603       30    298412K size-128        
...
```

Comment: Any network file systems, things like that?  What does `/usr/bin/slabtop` say?  The memory usage doesn't appear to be happening in user space, so take a closer look at kernel usage.

Comment: ok.... seems to be that way.... (see update)

Comment: does netstat -an show lots and lots of ESTABLISHED or SYN_SENT?

Comment: Not really. netstat -an | grep EST | wc -l = 129, SYN_SENT=0

Comment: I'm sorry: please run slabtop with these options: `/usr/bin/slabtop -o -s c` to sort it by cache size, and post the top few lines.  I should have been more specific.

Comment: What you see there is sorted (top three consumers)

Comment: what happens if you enable kernel threads in htop? what kernel is this? maybe it's leaking

Comment: PLease run this and post the result: "ps -eo pmem,pcpu,rss,vsize,args | sort -k 1 -r"

Comment: Could it be a RAM disk? http://askubuntu.com/questions/41040/how-do-i-get-the-actual-used-memory-including-ram-disks

Comment: Looks like you're hitting some ancient kernel bug — what's the kernel version there?

Answer (score 2):

If you're oom-ing, you almost certainly have an application that has a memory leak. Often the offender is the one the kernel selects to kill (but sometimes not).

Have you tried something like [memtop](http://code.google.com/p/memtop/)?

Comment: The user already provided `top` output, sorted by memory. Top is far more likely to be found on most distributions, and can provide the necessary information. If you have a *specific* option in mind for your memtop suggestion to provide better output, please supply that.

Comment: I was thinking memtop because it's specifically made to catch misbehaving, long-running processes: "Even though it resembles (h)top command by the output, this is intended to run over long periods of time (days/weeks/even months) and iterate in minutes or hours.

One of intended use is when you are trying to reduce memory consumption of your box or are trying to identify misbehaving application (memory leaks and so on). "

Comment: Also I was going to mention that it's a little suspicious that cpu1 is showing 100% iowait. Possibly something caught in a loop doing disk access?

Comment: All good stuff to add to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can execute

```
find /proc -name oom_score -exec echo -n "{}   " \; -exec cat {} \; | awk '{print  $2, $1| "sort -n" }
```

and check which app is candidate for oom kill -usually it consumes more memory-
It seems to me like an app running wild. Either allocates too many descriptors or some threads are not ending properly.

Answer (score 0):

slabtop is showing at least 1.3 GB of memory used in the slab.

Without seeing the rest of slabtop, it's hard to tell what was wrong, but if it's inodes or directory entries, these articles may help:

http://rackerhacker.com/2008/12/03/reducing-inode-and-dentry-caches-to-keep-oom-killer-at-bay/

http://people.arsc.edu/~kcarlson/software/man/drop_caches.html